# Changing variables in multiple instances using dat.gui

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dat.gui

I have a class which has been instantiated many times and I would like to change a certain instance variable for all of them. How would I go about doing this using dat.js?

e.g

```
function MyClass(){
   this.x = 1;
}
var arr = [];

for(var i =0; i< 10; i++){
   arr.push(new MyClass());
}
```

How can I alter the x variable for all instances of MyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I can think of to alter the instance variables without making any changes to `MyClass` would be to iterate over `arr`.

Alternatively, if you really mean for *all* instances to share a common property, maybe what you want to do is use something similar to a static variable in classical programming. These can be accomplished by taking advantage of the fact that functions are really just objects in JavaScript, so you can add a property to the function constructor: `MyClass.x = 1;`. When you want to change all instances' `x` value, you can update them at once just by changing `MyClass.x = 2;`. This technique alters the way you access the variable, so instead of `this.x` you'll need to reference it by `MyClass.x`.